# WPF ListView with Dynamic Row Heights

Tags: wpf, listview

I understand how to set *all* row heights. But the situation requires to display at different heights depending on the description field.

I have a TextBlock(description) wrapping inside of a ListView so it could be any hypothetical length (height=auto), then I would like to set a cap (max height).

Was hoping to be able to set the style to something like

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
<Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="500" />
```

But it just turns all rows to uniform heights.

Is this possible and if so how can I modify my template/style to allow for such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if I just change my TextBlock TextWrapping it will now accept Height=Auto

WAS:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Width="300" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

IS:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Width="300" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```